# Verilog Perceptron pipelined module output is one clock behind compared to given testbench

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga, vivado

I designed a single layer perceptron for a lab I need to finish. It is working perfectly as expected, and I am receiving the expected output compared to a testbench given to us. The only issue is that the output is exactly one clock too late compared to the testbench, and this is causing error log messages to appear. I have tried a lot to find where I went wrong, so any help is appreciated. Verilog and testbench code will be given below.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module perceptron(
    input rst_n,
    input clk,
    input signed [7:0] x1,
    input signed [7:0] x2,
    input valid_in,
    output reg y,
    output reg y_valid
    );
    
   reg signed [7:0] w1 = 8'sb00000010; //weight 1
   reg signed [7:0] w2 = 8'sb11111110; //weight 2
   reg signed [7:0] b = 8'sb11111101; //bias
   
   //stage 1: p1 = w1*x1 and p2 = w2*x2.
   //stage 2: s = p1 + p2 + b
   
   reg valid_pipe;
   reg signed [15:0] p1;
   reg signed [15:0] p2;
   reg signed [15:0] s;
   
   
   always @(posedge clk) begin 
        if (!rst_n) begin
            y <= 1'b0;
//            y_valid <= 1'b0;
//            w1 <= 8'b0;
//            w2 <= 8'b0;
//            b <= 8'b0;
            valid_pipe <= 1'b0;
//            p1 <= 16'b0;
//            p2 <= 16'b0;
//            s <= 16'b0;
                        
        end
        
        else begin
            //->first pipe cycle
            valid_pipe <= valid_in;
            p1 <= w1 * x1;
            p2 <= w2 * x2;
            //valid_pipe <= valid_in;
            
            //-->second pipe cycle
            //y_valid <= valid_pipe;
            s <= p1 + p2 + b;
            y <= (s >= 0) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
            y_valid <= valid_pipe;

            
            end 
          
        end
   
endmodule
```

Testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module tb_perceptron(
    );
    
    
reg clk;
reg rst_n;
    wire signed [7:0] x1;
    wire signed [7:0] x2;
    wire y;
    wire tb_y;
    reg valid_in; 
    wire y_valid;
    
    reg [3:0] addr_in, addr_y;
    
    perceptron dut (.*);   

    rom #( .addr_width (4), .data_width (8), .init_file("x1.dat") )
 x1_mem(                                                                   
.addr(addr_in),                                         
.data (x1)                                         
);    

    rom #( .addr_width (4), .data_width (8), .init_file("x2.dat") )
 x2_mem(                                                                   
.addr(addr_in),                                         
.data (x2)                                         
);    

    rom #( .addr_width (4), .data_width (1), .init_file("y.dat") )
 y_mem(                                                                   
.addr(addr_y),                                         
.data (tb_y)                                         
);    
    
    always #5 clk = ~clk;
    
    //integer file_handle;
    
    
    
    initial
        begin
        //file_handle = $fopen("output.txt", "w");
            //i edit here for delay for check. 
            //#5;
            clk = 0;
            rst_n = 1'h0;
            valid_in = 0;
            
            #73 rst_n = 1'h1;
            #17;
            addr_in = 4'h0;
            #20;
            valid_in = 1;
           
            for (integer i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1)
            begin
                #10;
                //assert (y == tb_y);
                addr_in = addr_in + 1;
            end 
            valid_in = 0;
            #50;
            //$fclose(file_handle);                  
        end
        
        always_ff @ (posedge clk)
            begin
                if (!rst_n)
                    begin
                        addr_y <= #0.1 4'h0;
                    end
                else if (y_valid)
                    begin
                     //$fwrite(file_handle, "%b\n", y);
                     assert (y == tb_y)
                     else $error("y not equal to tb_y");
                        addr_y <= #0.1 addr_y + 1;
                    end
            end
    
    
endmodule
```

ROM file:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module rom #(addr_width = 4, data_width = 4, string init_file = "dummy.dat" )
(
input [addr_width-1:0]addr,
output [data_width-1:0]data
);

reg [data_width-1:0] mem [ (1<<addr_width)-1:0];

initial
    begin
        $readmemb (init_file, mem);
        /*for (integer i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1)
        begin 
            mem[i] = 4'hf - i;
        end*/
    end
    
assign data = mem[addr];


endmodule
```

```
x1 dat: 
00000101
11111100
00000000
00001100
11111100
00000100
00000100
00000100
11111100
11111100
00100000
00000100
11111100
11111100
00000000
00000100


x2 dat:
11111010
00000100
00000000
11111100
00000100
11111100
11111100
00000100
11111100
00000100
11111100
11111100
00000000
11110000
00000100
11111100


y dat: 
1
0
0
1
0
1
1
0
0
0
1
1
0
1
0
1
```

I have tried moving around valid_in and asserting y_valid at different stages. Adding manual delays didn't help that much. I might have an error in the pipelining / sequential logic, so that might be the cause also. I am using AMD vivado.

Screenshot from sim:
[image: Output y vs testbench output tb_y]

Comment: added. there are dat files that import values, but they are visible on the waveform.

Comment: @toolic try now... all files with data posted

Answer (score 1):

Your pipeline stages are not same for `y` and `y_valid` in the else block of your module.

```
else begin

    valid_pipe <= valid_in;
    p1 <= w1 * x1;
    p2 <= w2 * x2;

    s <= p1 + p2 + b;
    y <= (s >= 0) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
    y_valid <= valid_pipe;
end
```

In the above simplified snippet, you can see that `y` takes 3 cycle (x1-->p1-->s-->y) to get to output and `y_valid` only take 2 cycles (valid_in-->valid_pipe -->y_valid).

And in the testbench you are using `y_valid` to capture the `y` with `y_tb`.

Solution is to either remove one pipeline form `y` path OR second solution is to add one pipeline stage in `y_valid` path.

```
else begin

    valid_pipe <= valid_in;
    p1 <= w1 * x1;
    p2 <= w2 * x2;

    s <= p1 + p2 + b;
    y <= (s >= 0) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
    y_valid_reg <= valid_pipe; //Additional Pipeline stage on valid
    y_valid <= y_valid_reg ;
end
```

add `reg y_valid_reg;` at the top as well.

Comment: did not work, do you think having two always blocks would help in that?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my reply... I did not properly added the pipeline stage properly. Now it is fixed. Check the edit, to see the update

Comment: @toolic edited with all needed files to reproduce on vivado.

Comment: @redpocket Have you tested with the new modifications?